# How can I cache images (express, node, object storage)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, aws-sdk, object-storage

I have an object storage and an express API that accesses the images via the aws-idk framework to resize them, but I have a problem, the process takes a long time. I tested this with Postman and found out the following:

The load time is 200ms on average, sometimes more, sometimes less, the target is 40/60ms, except for the first load.

I get the desired result when I cache the images on the server with the express instance. But can't the browser do that too, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something, why does my server need to cache the images? (Postman also has cache and with browsers like Edge or Chrome I have the same result)

Of course, I also send a cache control header that is set to 1 hour.

Unfortunately, the solution with caching on the express server is somehow unclear to me. As the images in the object memory are up to 32 MB in size *(the test images currently have a size of 50kb)*, the working memory fills up quite quickly.

What alternatives, solutions are there to get the images to the user quickly?

Thank you, for help :,)

Comment: One of the simple ways to address this is to use Image CDNs, e.g., Uploadcare, Imgix, ImageKit, etc. Have you considered this option?